# Weird and new asking panel at startup

Tags: xfce, startup, ubuntu-studio

I use Ubuntu Studio 18.04.2 LTS (64 bit Linux) in two desktop PCs (MSI MS-7788, Intel i5 at 3 GHZ, 8 GB RAM) and one HP 250 G5 Laptop PC (Intel Pentium at 1,6 GHZ, 8 GB RAM).

Two day ago I "opened" the backports upgrade to have access to any kind of upgrading from some specific Ubuntu Studio software.

Everything "normal", but... Since then, in my laptop, everytime I startup is appearing a new and very weird access panel, which asks me if I want to "restart" last session (as that session was "collapsed" or something), or start a "new" session.

This panel, as I said, is new to me and absolutely weird because there is not any "lost" and/or "collapsed" session.

This panel appears after I enter my user keyword and before the main xfce desktop screen appears.

This panel appears only in my laptop.

Sorry, because I don't have some media to take a picture of this.

Why this panel is here? and... How can I avoid this panel?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use xfce but I think that is a program that saves your last desktop session state and offers to restore it or start a new one. It's part of the xfce desktop setup if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I think I discovered the solution! There is a tool called "Session and Starting" into the "Configuration Panel" where we can click, or unclick, an option called: "Show the Session Selector". I unclicked it and... It doesn't appear, now! I'm not sure if this is the "official" solution but... It works for me!

Comment: Yes, it's the official solution! Please post an answer to this so others will benefit

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

1) Go to "Configuration Manager".

2) Go to "Session and Starting".

3) Go to "General" tab.

4) Look for the box called "Show the Session Selector".

5) Unclick that box.

6) Close the "Configuration Manager" and restart the machine.

That's all, folks!!!